# how to show multi delete in a list view in an ios app

Tags: android, ios, multi-selection, app, delete

i want to delete multiple row in a list view. how should it be designed? Swiping the row and showing check boxes is a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the design pattern established by Apple's Mail app when deleting multiple emails: Tap an Edit button in the upper right of the navbar to display checkboxes, then present a "Delete" button when one or more list items are checked.

I would limit the swipe gesture to deleting a single row item only, and not for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

1. Tap and hold an item.
2. The multiple selection mode automatically gets on. The action icons (including Delete) display somewhere on top toolbar.
3. Now tap on other items to select them.
4. After selecting all required items, tap on Delete icon.
5. Confirm from user and delete.

Comment: Do you have any mockups or design for this?

Comment: You can take help from this UI of iPad: http://ipadhelp.com/ipad-help-tips-tricks/how-to-remove-photos-from-the-ipad/

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a left to right swipe for single row deletion and on other hand you could provide a right to left swipe in which you could show check box for selection leading to multiple row deletion.

This is a unique design as so far I have not seen this anywhere and from UI perspective it will look good.

Also in UITableView already have left to right swipe and option with deletion so that you could need to work on swipe right to left part along with showing check box and delete button.